# Problems resuming Jetty 7 continuation when used with Spring MVC's @RequestBody

Tags: spring-mvc, jetty, jackson, long-polling

I'm trying to use Jetty continuation on a controller action that relies on `Spring MVC` `@RequestBody` + Jackson to deserialize a json request. Suspending the request works nicely, but when it's time to resume the connection (reply the request) Jackson has already "used" the request reader instance so deserializing the request body fail. At least this is my best theory so far.

```
public @ResponseBody MyResponse createTrip(@RequestBody MyRequest request, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    // De-serializing the request body fails the second time, most likely because 
    // Jackson has already exhausted the reader instance. 

    // ... continuation stuff
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that since Jackson by default closes input stream/reader after binding by default, this could mess up things. But there is a Jackson feature to prevent this auto-closing (`mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE, false)`, or something like this).

Comment: Very interesting! I'll give this a try when I have a spare moment. I assume that Jetty will take care of closing down any open streams and readers when the request has been processed if Jackson doesn't take care of it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to solve this using `@RequestBody` in reasonable time. But I was able to work around the problem by manually calling Jackson to unserialize the request during the initial method invocation.